# firebase functions notifications

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send simple push notifications using FCM services.

Every time my function is called, I want to receive one notification and I want my phone to ring and vibrate. I have 2 problems:

When I receive the notification, I get 5 of them instead of one.

The second problem is that if my phone's sound is activated when I receive the notifications, the phone doesn't vibrate or ring, but if it is on vibrations mode, it vibrates when I get the notifications.

Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks!

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Alerts/{email_encoded}/{alert_id}').onWrite(event => {

    const email_encoded = event.params.email_encoded;

    const alert_id = event.params.alert_id;

    const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${email_encoded}/device_token`).once('value');

    deviceToken.then(result => {

        const token_id = result.val();
        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: "Alert",
                body: "alert triggered",
                icon: "default",
                sound:"default",
                vibrate:"true"
            }
        };


      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload);
});

});
```

And the firebase database json structure:

```
"Alerts" : {
    "asdfgh@yahoo,com" : {
      "-KtXc_c7RMxysWGEb98L" : {
        "bid" : "1.30",
        "email" : "asdfgh@yahoo.com",
        "id" : "-KtXc_c7RMxysWGEb98L",
        "parity" : "EURUSD",
        "sign" : ">"
      },
      "-KtmCD7REa9AKK57xhXP" : {
        "bid" : "1.33",
        "email" : "asdfgh@yahoo.com",
        "id" : "-KtmCD7REa9AKK57xhXP",
        "parity" : "EURUSD",
        "sign" : ">"
      },
      "-KtmCpypQM_N1ub471Ta" : {
        "bid" : "1.333",
        "email" : "asdfgh@yahoo.com",
        "id" : "-KtmCpypQM_N1ub471Ta",
        "parity" : "EURUSD",
        "sign" : ">"
      }
    }
```

I tried sending a notification from the firebase dashboard. Even though at advanced settings I selected sound enabled, when I got the notification on my phone, it didn't vibrate or ring.

Comment: How are you writing data to `/Alerts/{email_encoded}/{alert_id}`? When you add data, are there multiple children being added separately? For example, you're adding `email_encoded` and `alert_id` as a child node of `/Alerts/{email_encoded}/{alert_id}`. Do you add each value separately? Because each one would be considered a write and trigger `onWrite`

Comment: @JenPerson https://gyazo.com/285cbc5663e1d9227fb3a3885743be9d

Comment: When I add data, it just creates another child with a random ID below the encoded email (that with @yahoo,com)

Comment: So there are 5 children, which is why it's being called 5 times. You can instead use `.onCreate`, which is triggered the first time data is added to the node instead of any time it's added, changed, or deleted. Also please update your question to include the structure of the database. Please write the database code in JSON format because this makes it easier for people to test and you're likely to get more responses.

Comment: Now I get only 1 notification, thank you very much @JenPerson !! . The sound is still messed up, I have to look into it further more. I have also updated my question, thanks!

Comment: @JenPerson I have noticed that if I use .onUpdate, I receive notifications when I create a new alert too. Any idea how can I receive the notification only when the alert gets updated? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Nevermind, I have added a boolean which is true only after the function updates, and I am returning the norification only if the boolean is true. Works really good!

Comment: Glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that on my phone my notification sound was off. I added a sound "mysound" in my android /res/raw and changed `sound:"default"`to `sound:"mysound"` and now I even get the sound I want when I receive the notification.